# How to make Pipewire (or whatever) use the LDAC codec automatically when connecting my bluetooth headset automatically

Tags: linux, bluetooth, connection, codec, pipewire

**Problem:**
Whenever I turn on my Bluetooth headset it connects automatically to my pc choosing the "HSP/HFP" codec. This coded sounds terrible.

**Additional info:**
When I click "disconnect" on the Fedora KDE Plasma bluetooth controls and subsequently click on "reconnect", the correct LDAC codec ist activated and it works flawlessly. I only use the Headset as a playback device.

- My System: Fedora 39 KDE Plasma, Pipewire, Wayland
- Bluetooth-Adaptor: ASUS BT-500, Chipset: RTL8761B
- Headset: OneMore Triple Driver

**Question:**
How can I make my pc to use the LDAC codec automatically even when I connect the headset by powering it on?